# Are not the field equations proof of the holographic principle?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, holographic-principle

The field equations (e.g. Schrödinger’s/Maxwell’s) describe the four-dimensional universe as the time evolution of a three-dimensional system.  This implies that the universe contains only three dimensions of information: the fourth is derivable deterministically (albeit not practically) from the other three via these formulas.

My understanding is that this is exactly what the holographic principle posits: that the universe contains only three dimensions of information (commonly presented as two spatial, one temporal).  Yet the holographic principle remains unproven.  Where is my misunderstanding?

Comment: 3+1 dimensions is still 4 dimensions. I'm afraid I don't quite understand your assertion

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to?  My second paragraph talks about 2+1, not 3+1.

Comment: The Maxwell equations specify dynamics in 3+1=4 dimensions. There is nothing holographic about them.

Comment: Yes I know.  They deterministically specify the time evolution of a three-dimensional system.  Given a 3-dimensional initial condition (let's say the hyperplane at t=0, but x=0 or y=z work equally well), the equations describe a unique four-dimensional field; i.e. they project from 3 to 4 dimensions.  Is this not the very definition of a hologram?

Comment: Holography would be if one could describe the dynamics by only referring to three coordinates, not 3+1. These equations clearly feature all 4, and are thus not holographic.

Comment: It seems you are implying that the holographic principle states that the universe can be described by equations relating three dimensions deterministically (as opposed to three dimensions unconstrained by any equations), and hence the universe contains only two dimensions of information?

Comment: You should just read up on the topic on wikipedia to get a better idea what it is about. I dont think that there exists any classical holographic systems, so one should not talk of deterministism regardless. It is also dangerous to think of time as something completely different from space, which you seem to be doing.

Comment: I'm 100% clear that time is no different from space.  See my comment about arbitrarily slicing the 4-space along a hyperplane.  I've already "read up on the topic".  I'll wait for another answer as it seems we're talking past each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An intuitive description (or rather a caricature) of the dimensional reduction associated with the holographic principle run as follows.

We live in a 4D spacetime. Fields propagate over this 4D spacetime with the Big Bang providing a 3D 'initial condition' to these fields. One would therefore expect the amount of information required to specify the full 4D universe to be proportional to the 3D initial volume.

According to the holographic principle this is incorrect.

[image]

Suppose you take a snapshot of the universe with an omni-directional camera (see picture). The photons reaching the camera at the moment of the snapshot trace out a 3D light cone. What is 'happening' on this 3D light cone one can think of having propagated from the 3D initial volume to the light cone (in the picture three arbitrary world lines indicate this causal influence). So one would expect the information required to fully describe the light cone to be proportional to the 3D initial volume embraced by this light cone.

This is incorrect. Rather, the holographic principle states that the information contained in the 3D light cone is proportional to the surface area of the 2D boundary to the light cone.

In rough terms, you can think of this dimensional reduction to be related to a (non-local) field theory for the 3D light cone that forms a dual description to the local field equations 'living' in the 4D spacetime contained within this light cone.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense.  So my belief that the holographic principle posits 3 dimensions of information is incorrect; it posits in fact only 2.  Crazy!